# How can I customize width of the views in SplitView in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin.mac

[image]

I am try to fit two views in single page using SplitView, one view present in left side and another present in right side of the screen. These two view's are separated by separator line. I want to customize width of these two view's . How can I change the width of the view's in SplitView. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need this API: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nssplitview/1455316-setposition?language=objc

which is bound as:

```
    void SetPositionOfDivider (nfloat position, nint dividerIndex);
```

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/master/src/appkit.cs#L13796

Comment: Thanks @Chris, when I change width of the views in Split view controller it' only changes the view size but I want change the position of views separator in split view controller i.e divider of these two views.

Comment: Does not SetPositionOfDivider set the position of the separator? I'm not following otherwise.

Comment: yes chris, I want to set the position of the separator and another thing is how can I fix two views between the separator is not drag mode.